# How can I use the same anchor point angles for multiple shapes?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I'm making a design with the following shape:

[image: design]

I'm trying to make both sides of this diamond shaped object have an identical angle (using the Anchor Point Tool).

I've tried to manually replicate it on both sides, but haven't been successful.

Comment: Draw half. Reflect a copy, join, round corners

Comment: @Scott the design has already been drawn. I'm editing a really old design I had, so I can't remake it from scratch

Comment: Well, as far as I'm aware, there's no way to mirror existing anchor points. The *best* you can do is look at angles and measurements in the Info panel and try to match them manually.

Comment: Cut in half, edit, mirror join

Answer (score 2):

**If it's already a vector shape**, cut it in half by deleting the anchors on one side, reflect a copy of what's left, and rejoin to make the sides symmetrical.

---

If it's *not* a vector object.... redraw half the shape, tracing the original, then use the **Reflect Tool** and click the `Copy` Button. Then join the two halves.

[image]

To the best of my knowledge, there's no mechanism to symmetrically edit more than one existing anchor point, or existing Bezier handle. There are perhaps some third-party plug-ins which used to do that (i.e. Better Handles), but I don't know if they still exist for CC versions.

Comment: You can mirror with the transform effect. That would be live.

Comment: ////////////////    True